# pygame.error No video mode large enough

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen

I have been working on a game using the pygame module for python and am having an issue getting it to display properly on other computers. When I first starting writing I chose a resolution of (1400,1000). There was no real reason for this choice, I was/am new to programming and it seemed like a nice round number. The issue I am having is that on many laptops the screen is bigger than the max resolution. I can run it in windowed mode but then the screen runs off to the right and the bottom and there are things that the user cannot see. I then tried to run it in full screen mode, but then I get the error message "pygame.error No video mode large enough for 1400 , 1000"

The most obvious solution is to reduce my screen resolution I suppose, but all my GUI menu buttons are blitted to the screen assumming a resolution of (1400,1000) and changing everything would be extremely tedious.

The most curious thing happens when I connect a USB moniter with a resolution high enough to display it properly; The game will display properly on the connected moniter, **and will also resize itself to display properly on the laptop moniter as well**!. I can then disconnect the other moniter and go about playing the game no problem!

If I could somehow "trick" the computer into thinking there is a moniter connected with a proper resolution everything would work perfect. Not a perfect or elegant solution I admit, but I loathe having to go back and redo my entire GUI...

```
size = (1400, 1000)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: ".. changing everything would be extremely tedious": your computer can calculate the difference between your design size and the actual one.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on pygame.org/docs

pygame.display.set_mode() will use your current screen resolution automatically, no matter what computer you are on as long as you **don't pass in any parameters.**

As to why 1400 by 1000 wasn't working for you, that is not a common screen resolution (not even sure if it exists). Some common ones include:

1280 by 720

1600 by 900

1920 by 1200

"The most obvious solution is to reduce my screen resolution I suppose, but all my GUI menu buttons are blitted to the screen assumming a resolution of (1400,1000) and changing everything would be extremely tedious."

A way to avoid this issue is to work in terms of your screen area. For example, lets say I work in a resultion of 1280 by 800.

```
width = 1280
height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
```

I want my position to be in the middle of the screen. Instead of saying

```
position = 1280 / 2 # Hardcoded
```

do

```
position = width/2
```

Now no matter what you change your screen width to, your position will be preserved. I recommend looking into http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html for information about how to track locations in pygame in a nice way.

About the flags: I don't know much about these so I won't say much, other than that I never use them and don't have any issues doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps

```

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
size = (width, height)
```

```

I would try to incorporate this into into your code